# String to array conversion in python

Tags: python

I have a **string** in my `python` like:

```
str = "[3705049, 3705078, 3705082, 3705086, 3705093, 3705096]"
```

Now I need to convert it to an **array** or **list** like:

```
arr = [3705049, 3705078, 3705082, 3705086, 3705093, 3705096]
```

I have tried like this:

```
str = "[3705049, 3705078, 3705082, 3705086, 3705093, 3705096]"
arr = list(str)
print(arr)
```

But it provides output like this:

```
['[', '3', '7', '0', '5', '0', '4', '9', ',', ' ', '3', '7', '0', '5', '0', '7', '8', ',', ' ', '3', '7', '0', '5', '0', '8', '2', ',', ' ', '3', '7', '0', '5', '0', '8', '6', ',', ' ', '3', '7', '0', '5', '0', '9', '3', ',', ' ', '3', '7', '0', '5', '0', '9', '6', ']']
```

Please suggest how can I fix this?

Comment: `ast.literal_eval(str)`

Comment: you need to `import ast`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use json.loads to load your datas:

```
import json
string = "[3705049, 3705078, 3705082, 3705086, 3705093, 3705096]"

arr = [3705049, 3705078, 3705082, 3705086, 3705093, 3705096]

print(json.loads(string) == arr)
```